# Hive storage in Hadoop, interesting finding but don't understand

Tags: hadoop, hive, storage

Here is a finding on hive/hadoop, I have a table called titles, I splitted it into two portions, one is titles20000 and the other is titles20000more, the row counts look good, however the data size look different, see the screenshot here which is from the namenode by typing "host address:50070" in browser:
[image]

Look at the Block Size, the first table titles has 4 blocks, while the splitted sub tables only have 1 for each.

I also checked the dataSize another way by executing show property in hive:
[image]

I did a quick calculation on row counts:

```
n = titles: 443309
n1 = titles20000: 14781
n2 = titles20000more: 428528
n = n1 + n2 = 443309
% of n1 =  3%
% of n2 = 97%
```

This is correct.

I then did another quick calculation on totalSize:

```
n = titles: 19934943
n1 = where emp_no < 20000: 624642
n2 = where emp_no >=20000: 18423685
n1+n2 = 19048327 < n
```

Apparently this matches the previous observation, the question is:

For the original table titles, it used 4 128MB blocks
For the splitted second table titles20000more, it contains 97% of rows and yet uses only 1 128MB Block

In the first screenshot, what's the meaning of Size (the 4th column)?

How could this happenes?

Answer (score 1):

**Size** is the actual size of the data.

**Block Size** is the size of the block within which the data is stored.

Your original table uses four blocks as its data was created by a Map-only job using four Mappers. When the data was copied into the other tables, it appears to have been merged into a single block.

Comment: Thanks but no, I used only 1 mapper.

Comment: The m-0000x file naming shows that there were 4 Mappers. You might want to check whichever job you used to ingest data.

Comment: @BenWatson, I have already seen a lot of confusion about what "block size" means, so IMHO you could make things more explicit by saying --  **Block Size** is an indication that, if the file ever grows larger that 128 MB, it will be split into several *logical* allocation units (named "blocks"). Different blocks may be stored on different DataNodes. Different blocks will be processed by different Mappers. It's an internal Hadoop trick to manage *Big* data.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter yes I understand there is a default block size of 128MB, and just as indicated by BenWatson, maybe for some reason a 4 mappers job was used to ingest the data although I don't recall that, nor do I think there would be a reason to use 4 mappers, however, the 4-mappers explaination seems make sense here to have created 4 blocks of the original table titles?